# Why does Sum() result increase with each column added to subquery? What to do about it?

Tags: sql

Consider these two short scripts.

1

```
select year, sum(traffic) 
from (
  select year, count(distinct id) traffic 
  from table.name 
  where clean_url like "%.com/blog/%" 
  group by 1
) 
GROUP BY 1
```

-- result 3078347

2

```
select year, sum(traffic) 
from (
  select year, month, count(distinct id) traffic 
  from table.name 
  where clean_url like "%.com/blog/%" 
  group by 1,2
) GROUP BY 1
```

-- result 3149904

script 2 includes month. The inclusion of this additional field increases the result.

table.name is a user action table that includes year, month, visit_date, entry_url, and id.

1. Why? Shouldn't they be the same?
2. what do I do about it? I've tried all manner of solutions and I'm stuck. The FINAL script has 16 additional fields, increasing the sum 500k.

I've never encountered this behavior before. Please help!

Comment: Because if `id1` was in your table for months March and May, your second table will count it two times, while first - only once.

Comment: You can't `sum(count(distinct))`. Well, you can, but should not. It has no meaning.

Comment: please elaborate. How does it have no meaning?

Comment: count(distinct id) = int. why can't I sum that resulting int, and group it by any number of fields I want?

Comment: Mathematically you can, but this sum is meaningless as statistics. Imagine your blog had two unique visitors this month, and two unique visitors next month, but they were the same two people. Your first query will return 2 (correctly), but your second - 4.

Comment: it might not be fully meaningless, e.g. the number of distinct visitors in a year has some meaning, and so does the number of distinct visitors in a month, but these sets of visitors can contain repeated visitors, hence the numbers will differ in response to the time periods being used. e.g. 3078347 <> 3149904 because of repeated visits by some visitors.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell, I challenge you to explain me meaning of value 4 from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

One counts each id once for every year it occurs in, and the other counts each id once for every month it occurs in.  These give different answers because...well of course they do.  They are different queries doing different things.  The way to "fix" it is to figure out what you want, and use the query that does that.

Answer (score 0):

If an `Id` appears in more than one `month` of a `year`, then the second query will return a higher number. Assume this is your data (no other rows):

| Id | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023 | Jan |
| 1 | 2023 | Feb |

The first subquery would return one row with `traffic=1`, because it is the only Id in Year 2023. The second subquery would return two rows: one for each Year & Month combination, each with traffic=1. The outer query simply sums the traffic values returned: 1 for the first query, and 2 for the second.